# LINQ to SQL paging performance decreases as the number of rows increases

Tags: sql-server-2008, optimization, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Server database with a view that returns a large number of rows. In my project the view is being sorted and paged by LinqToSql to be shown in a data grid.

The performance for loading the first page is acceptable, but as paging further into the view the speed of loading each page is decreased. Reaching the last pages of the view, it is taking very long to load the page.

The SQL that is generated by linq-to-sql to page is

```
SELECT [t1].[Client Id]
       ...
FROM  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[Last Name]) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
              [t0].[Client Id],
              ...
       FROM [dbo].[View_MemberEligibilitySearch] AS [t0]) AS [t1]
       WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 50 /* @p0 */ + 1 AND 50 /* @p0 */ + 15 /* @p1 */
       ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Is there any way that this can be optimized from the SQL Server point of view? There are already all the indexes needed in the tables that are used to generate the view. Can indexes be added to the view itself to improve the performance of this kind of query?

I realize that this problem can be solved by not using views but i am looking for something that would not require significant code changes.

Is there any way that paging views through Linq-To-Sql be effective?

EDIT

Some more details.
The view currently has 350k records.
It takes o seconds for the first 10 and 15 seconds for the last.  The timing is similar to selecting the full table.

Execution plan is taking 99% on Clustered index scan of the table that has the same 350k records. (All other parts of the view are look up tables that are taking virtually no time as they are coming from primary keys)

This problem can be reproduced on any View
create a view from
select * from MyBigTable

Map table in LinqToSql
Call

MyTable.Skip(100000).Take(10)

Comment: It would be useful to give a little more information: how many rows is a "large number", and what is the execution plan for the query?

Comment: @Pondlife I included the info that i thought was relevant from the execution plan.  Is there any better way to provide it?

Comment: It's best to provide the actual execution plan, in XML or text format (the [XML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189298(v=sql.105).aspx) can be opened in SSMS).